# Using conditional formatting for exact match text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight cells in a column that contain an exact word with Excel 2012. I am only having partial success using "cells that contain text" function. The issue is that I want to highlight only those cells that contain the exact word "tea". However, cells that contain the word "instead" are also highlighted because the word "tea" is inside "instead", which I don't want. I only want to highlight cells that have "tea" in them. Is this possible.

Another thing is that I don't want any capitalization bias. I want instances of "tea", "Tea", and "TEA" to be highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find an exact word in a cell, you're going to have to use a VBA function, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with Excel functions alone.

Specifically, the following function seems to work well:

```
Function ExactWordInString(Text As String, Word As String) As Boolean
    ExactWordInString = " " & UCase(Text) & " " Like "*[!A-Z]" & UCase(Word) & "[!A-Z]*"
End Function
```

Source: [Spreadsheet Page Excel Tips: Is A Particular Word Contained In A Text String?](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/is_a_particular_word_contained_in_a_text_sring)

To use it:

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
2. In the Project window, right-click and select Insert → Module
3. Paste the code above
4. Back in the workbook, highlight your cells and go to Conditional Formatting → New Rule...
5. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
6. Enter the following formula: `=ExactWordInString(A1, "tea")`
7. Click "Format..." and select your formatting options, then click **OK** twice

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this option before also, and just tried again, but it still highlights cells with "instead" in them

Comment: @Darren See updated post with screenshots. Are you sure you tried that exact option? I can't imagine it would work differently in Excel 2010.

Comment: Hi, yep I tried that but didn't work. Here is a screen cast showing the 3 options I tried.                                                   http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cl66lO93h

Comment: @Darren This may be a long shot, but did you actually clear the formatting from the first attempt? I noticed that on the third try you seemed to set a much darker background colour than the rows you then pointed at, which might mean that the "Text that Contains" formatting rule is still active.

Comment: Hey there - after each fomatting attempt i hit "ctrl+z" to undo the action, but of course you can't see that on the screen. That does clear out the highlighting in the cells before i try the next formatting option. Does that mean the rule has been removed too?

Comment: Check Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules to be sure, or just clear all rules (Conditional Formatting -> Clear Rules).

Comment: I just uploaded another screencast. This time I clear conditional formatting between each formatting attempt, as clearly shown in the vid. Curiously, I get no results at all when using equal to function, but get too many results, including the "instead", when using the cells containing text function http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cl66lM93T

Comment: Ah, it seems I've misunderstood you. I thought you wanted to highlight cells that contain "tea" and nothing else, but you want to highlight cells that contain the *word* "tea", but not cells that contain the letters "tea" in that order as part of another word. I'll try and find a way to do that.

Comment: that is wonderful - thank you! Also I tried to using "tea " with a space after it as a workaround, but that didn't work, excel still highlighted instance of cells that contain the letters "tea" as well as the word "tea".

Comment: Ok, so as an extra note. I got this problem partially solved by using find and replace before using conditional formatting. I find and replace all instances of "tea " (with the space) with "THISWORD ", and then replace "tea|" with "THISWORD|". That at least gets me half way there. The problem is that the other instances of tea in the spreadsheet inclusde " tea", I cannot change this because there are words such as " teacher", that I don't want. The other issue is when "tea" is right at the end of the cell with no space after it.

Comment: See updated answer for a possible solution. I tested it with a couple of values that I saw in your screencasts, but if there are any that it fails to highlight (or hightlights mistakenly), let me know and I'll see if I can amend the code accordingly.

Comment: Indrek - thanks so much, that did the job perfectly. This will save me a lot of time and hassle. I appreciate you helping me out on this

Comment: @Darren Glad to hear it worked. Please mark this answer as accepted (by clicking the green checkmark outline next to it), as well as upvote it.

Comment: I clicked the green check mark, but I don't have the rep yet to give you the thumbs up. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4):

In `Format only cells that contain`, you can use `Cell value` and choose `equal to`, and insert "tea" in the last field.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this option before, and just tried again, but it still highlights cells with "instead" in them

Comment: Weird, it works here... Then I don't know!

Comment: Worked for me (Excel 2010).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any punctuation in the cells? If not then this formula-based solution should work for you:

Assuming data in `column A`, select that column and apply conditional formatting using the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option, with this formula

`=SEARCH(" tea "," "&A1&" ")`

**SEARCH** is not case-sensitive. Formula searches for "tea" with a space either side, within text contents with a space either side, so that will capture **Tea** at the start, or **tea** at the end but not **Team** or **instead**

Punctuation can mess this up as it won't find **tea,** (with an immediately following comma) for example. To cater for that you can add SUBSTITUTE functions to the formula to remove those, e.g. if you might have commas and full-stops (periods) use this version

`=SEARCH(" tea "," "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),".","")&" ")`

Answer (score 0):

under conditional formatting, use the "Use a formula to select which cells to format" option.

enter:

=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A*)), A* = "tea")
(where A* is the 1st cell in the range you want to format)

add a second rule for the same range and enter the formula:

=NOT(AND(ISBLANK(A*))

Make sure that the 1st rule (selecting for "tea" is 1st (on top)

This will make any cell that's not blank format according to the second rule, and then any cell that contains only "tea" will format according to the 1st rule.